# Finding maximum value of a discrete function

Tags: maximum

I have the following function. I want to graph its discrete plot and find the points where it takes on the highest value:

```
20*Log[20] - N2*Log[N2] - N3*Log[N3]-(20 - N2 - N3)*Log[20 - N2 - N3];

N2=Range[20];
N3=Range[20];
```

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html

Answer (score 7):

```
f[N2_, N3_] := 
  20*Log[20] - N2*Log[N2] - N3*Log[N3] - (20 - N2 - N3)*Log[20 - N2 - N3];
```

For the continuous function

```
max = NMaximize[
  {f[N2, N3], 1 <= N2 <= 18, 1 <= N3 <= 19 - N2},
  {N2, N3}, Reals]

(*  {21.9722, {N2 -> 6.66667, N3 -> 6.66667}}  *)

f[20/3, 20/3] // Simplify

(*  20 Log[3]  *)

% // N

(*  21.9722  *)
```

For the discrete function

```
maxInt = Maximize[
  {f[N2, N3], 1 <= N2 <= 18, 1 <= N3 <= 19 - N2},
  {N2, N3}, Integers]

(*  {-6 Log[6] - 14 Log[7] + 20 Log[20], {N2 -> 6, N3 -> 7}}  *)

maxInt[[1]] // N

(*  21.9213  *)
```

From the expression's symmetry

```
f[6, 7] == f[7, 6] == f[7, 7]

(*  True  *)

Show[
 Plot3D[f[N2, N3],
  {N2, 1, 18}, {N3, 1, 19 - N2},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]],
 Graphics3D[{Thick,
   Table[{
     Gray,
     Line[{
       {N2, N3, f[N2, N3]},
       {N2, N3, 0}}],
     If[N2 == 6 && N3 == 7 ||
       N2 == 7 && N3 == 6 ||
       N2 == 7 && N3 == 7, Red, Green],
     AbsolutePointSize[6],
     Point[{N2, N3, f[N2, N3]}]},
    {N2, 1, 18}, {N3, 1, 19 - N2}]}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"N2", "N3", "f"})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just a brute force approach:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := With[{r = {20, -x, -y, -z}}, r.Log[Abs@r]]
ip = IntegerPartitions[20, {3}];
ord = Ordering[N[f @@@ ip]];
ans = Last@ip[[ord]]
can = Catenate[Permutations /@ ip];
pnt[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, f[x, y, z]}
With[{c = pnt @@@ can}, Graphics3D[{Yellow, PointSize[0.015], Point[c],
   MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {(c /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y, 0}), c}],
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pnt @@@ Permutations[ans]]}, 
  Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Background -> Black]]
```

[image]

Note: edited to remove misleading `DiscretePlot3D` showing points at places non-real values.